# Moto SNS client can't get publishing working AttributeError: 'sns.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'publish'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, moto

I'm trying to mock SNS with Moto, using examples from the docs with pytest.

sns.create_topic() works but sns.publish() does not. From the boto docs I should be able to call publish() like this:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def aws_credentials():
    """Mocked AWS Credentials for moto."""
    os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] = "testing"
    os.environ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] = "testing"
    os.environ["AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN"] = "testing"
    os.environ["AWS_SESSION_TOKEN"] = "testing"


@pytest.fixture()
def sts(aws_credentials):
    with mock_sts():
        yield boto3.client("sts", region_name="us-east-1")


@pytest.fixture
def sns(aws_credentials):
    with mock_sns():
        yield boto3.resource("sns", region_name="us-east-1")

@mock_sts
def test_publish(sns):
    resp = sns.create_topic(Name="sdfsdfsdfsd")
    mesg = {"TopicArn": "arnsdfsdf", "Message": "sdfsdfsdfsd"}
    response = sns.publish(mesg)
```

I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'sns.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'publish'

Does Moto not support publish? I would like it to valid the call made to publish() is valid for me - I'd like to not have to monkey-patch publish.

Answer (score 1):

SNS uses a boto3 client, instead of a resource.
So change this:

```
with mock_sns():
    yield boto3.resource("sns", region_name="us-east-1")
```

to this:

```
with mock_sns():
    yield boto3.client("sns", region_name="us-east-1")
```

and it should work.

Example test case: https://github.com/spulec/moto/blob/master/tests/test_sns/test_publishing_boto3.py#L28